# Prove that there exist a function $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $v=grad(f)$.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $v$ be a differentiable vector field defined in an open set  $U\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$ a simply-connected, and that $rot(v)=0$. Prove that there exist a function $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $v=grad(f)$. Furthermore for any curve $c$ joining the points $p_{1},p_{2}\in U$, $$\int_{c}{v}=f(p_{2})-f(p_{1})$$

My approach: If $U\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$, then by definition
$$rot(v)=\left(\dfrac{\partial v^{3}}{\partial x^{2}}-\dfrac{\partial v^{2}}{\partial x^{3}}\right)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{1}}+\left(\dfrac{\partial v^{3}}{\partial x^{1}}-\dfrac{\partial v^{1}}{\partial x^{3}}\right)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{2}}+\left(\dfrac{\partial v^{2}}{\partial x^{1}}-\dfrac{\partial v^{1}}{\partial x^{2}}\right)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{3}}=0$$
this implies $$\dfrac{\partial v^{3}}{\partial x^{2}}=\dfrac{\partial v^{2}}{\partial x^{3}}, \dfrac{\partial v^{3}}{\partial x^{1}}=\dfrac{\partial v^{1}}{\partial x^{3}} \mbox{,} \dfrac{\partial v^{2}}{\partial x^{1}}=\dfrac{\partial v^{1}}{\partial x^{2}}$$

But now how I can prove exist such $f$?? Regards

Comment: What is your working definition of "simply connected"?

Answer (score 0):

The approach with the curve integral is good. You need the condition $\operatorname{rot}(v)=0$ so that the integral has the same value even if the curve takes another path. For that it is enough to show that the integral over every closed curve is zero.
If you have done that you can follow the [proof on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem#Converse_of_the_gradient_theorem).